# Keycloak Docker setup with Spring

Tags: java, spring, docker, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I want to deploy a Spring microservices application using Docker Compose.

I have a Keycloak container running with a public *Authorization Code Flow (with PKCE)* client configured and now I want to authenticate with a webapp that's hosted on another server or with a mobile app.

I have set the `KC_HOSTNAME_URL` of the Keycloak container to the public IP like `http://1.2.3.4:8080` and in my webapp I have set the authority URL to `http://1.2.3.4:8080/realms/my-realm` (using `oidc-react` package).

This way general authentication with Keycloak works.
But when I want to make a request to one of my services with the received token, Spring gives me the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Issuer "http://1.2.3.4:8080/realms/my-realm" provided in the configuration did not match the requested issuer "http://keycloak:8080/realms/my-realm"
```

This makes sense, because my services are configured with `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://keycloak:8080/realms/my-realm`, when running inside docker.

I just don't know what I am missing in order to obtain a token using a public IP/Domain from a public client on the one hand and on the other hand validating that token inside docker using docker-internal names.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question because I am struggling with the same thing?

Comment: Not a really satisfying one. I basically just use the public URI everywhere, instead of the docker-internal one.
There should also be the possibility to override the validation logic inside the spring resource server. But I didn't try that out yet. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-validation-custom